# Cannot Scrape Data from Bloomberg Website using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I just simply wanted to scrape the "Title" and the "published date" on this website bloomberg and I am sure that I am using correct response.xpath but It always get none.

```
response.xpath("//h1[@class = 'lede-text-v2__hed']").extract_first()
response.xpath("//meta[@property = 'og:title']/@content").extract_first()
```

Neither of two I cannot get the title

also in published date

```
response.xpath("//time[@class = 'article-timestamp']/@datetime").extract_first()
```

it's getting none, Any idea please?

here's the URL

```
https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-05-30/tesla-dealt-another-blow-as-barclays-sees-it-as-niche-carmaker
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are being detected as a bot.

Use `scrapy shell <url>` and `view(response)` to see the response you are receiving.

Measures to avoid being detected include:

- Use a smart proxy if you can afford one.
- Try to make your requests more similar to those of your web browser.
- Use Splash.

In the two latter cases, be ready to also use multiple proxies in case they ban your IP address due to unexpectedly high activity.

Comment: Hi @gallaecio, thank you for helping me I am actually using scrapy shell to test and I just get nothing, also I already have crawlera (smart proxy). Any idea please?

Comment: In those cases where Crawlera does not work yet, Splash usually does the work for me.

Comment: I am not used to splash, is it possible to use scrapy only?

Comment: The general approach to counter anti-bot measures is to imitate your web browser as much as possible. It is doable from Scrapy, but you’ll have to put some time into it, see what your browser does, try to imitate your browser as close as possible, and once you’ve figured out the right way you also need to retry requests when you know you’ve been detected and make your approach work with Crawlera to avoid getting IP banned.

Comment: This is really hard for me, thank you @gallaecio for helping me and giving me an advice for this, really appreciated